# How to spam numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, numbers

I want from script to do
1
2
3
4
5...
But it give me 499.
What I need to add to the script is not to add numbers but just to print them

```
function numbers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var spam = i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('demo20').innerHTML = spam;
}
```

Comment: Look at where your `i` starts and ends.

Comment: Move the `innerHTML` assignment into the `for` loop, and concatenate instead of assigning.

Comment: initialize `spam` outside of the loop and then do `+=`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function numbers() {
  const demo20 =  document.getElementById('demo20');
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
   demo20.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", i + "<br>");
  }
}

numbers();
```

```html
<div id="demo20"></div>
```

If you want a small delay in printing:

```js
async function numbers() {
  const demo20 = getElementById('demo20');
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    demo20.getElementById('demo20').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", i + "<br>");
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 100));
  }
}

numbers();
```

```html
<div id="demo20"></div>
```

Comment: @Ivar updated, if you care about performance that much

Answer (score 1):

Your spam variable is constantly overwritten and at the end of the loop it has the value 499. You need to concatenate the variable with itself.

```
  var spam = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var spam += i + "<br>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function numbers() {
  var spam = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
     spam += i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('demo20').innerHTML = spam;
}
```